# 413 on XHR using scrapy, works fine in requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some data from an online GIS system that uses XML.  I was able to whip up a quick script using the requests library that successfully posted a payload and returned a HTTP 200 with the correct results but when moving the request over to scrapy, I continually get a `413`.  I inspected the two requests using Wireshark and found a few differences, though I'm not totally sure I understand them.

The request in scrapy looks like:

```
    yield Request(
        self.parcel_number_url,
        headers={'Accept': '*/*',
                 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
                 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                 'Content-Length': '823',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
                 'Host': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                 'Origin': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                 'Referer': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36',
                 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        method='POST',
        cookies={'_ga': 'GA1.3.1332485584.1402003562', 'PHPSESSID': 'tpfn5s4k3nagnq29hqrolm2v02'},
        body=PAYLOAD,
        callback=self.parse
    )
```

The packets I inspected are located here: http://justpaste.it/fxht

That includes the HTTP request when using the requests library and the HTTP request when yielding a scrapy Request object.  The request seems to be larger when using scrapy, it looks like the 2nd TCP segment is 21 bytes larger than the 2nd TCP segment when using the requests library.  The Content-Length header gets set twice in the scrapy request as well.

Has anyone ever experienced this kind of problem with scrapy?  I've never gotten a 413 scraping anything before.

Comment: I resolved this by removing the cookies and not setting the "Content-Length" header manually on my yielded request.  It seems like those 2 things were the extra 21 bytes on the 2nd TCP segment and caused the 413 response.

Maybe the server was interpreting the "Content-Length" as the combined value of the 2 "Content-Length" headers and therefore returning a 413, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by removing the cookies and not setting the "Content-Length" header manually on my yielded request. It seems like those 2 things were the extra 21 bytes on the 2nd TCP segment and caused the 413 response. Maybe the server was interpreting the "Content-Length" as the combined value of the 2 "Content-Length" headers and therefore returning a 413, but I'm not certain.